# Words meaning "aggressively cut down" and "very large number of trees"

Tags: word-request

Those are some notices (in parenthesis) for the mistake (in bold) I made in a sentence. But I don't know how to fix it.

> Due to the lucrative profit from this practice, people and companies don't hesitate to **intensely** (wrong word) cut down **myriad trees** (wrong form) and become more violent.

I know I was using the wrong word but for "intensely cut down", I meant people become harsh and more aggressive/hunger in cutting down trees, so I use the adverb "intensely". And for "myriad", I meant a very large number of trees.

Please help me find the correction to them and if you can give me some explanation, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something more like:

> Because this practice is very lucrative, people and companies don't hesitate to aggressively cut down a myriad of trees and become more violent.

"lucrative profit" is redundant, because "lucrative" implies profits. One could write "lucrative nature" to keep the form closer to the original. One could write "intensively" in place of "intensely", but I think "aggressively" conveys the meaning better.  While "myriad" does technically mean  10,000, the form "a myriad of" is normally used to mean "an unspecified but very large number of". [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/myriad) says that "myriad" as an adjective means "innumerable". 
"

Comment: Thanks a lot! This sounds so much better! But do you think the last part "become more violent" is redundant also? Because "aggressively" already covers it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "[clear-cut](https://ofri2017.dhxadv.com/index.php/content/clearcutting)" instead of "intensely cut down"?

Do you mean "forests" instead of "myriad trees"?

Even though "myriad" is not idiomatic, it is accurate.  Many people use "[myriad](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/myriad)" to mean "a very large number".  But technically, a "myriad" is 10,000.  A typical almond orchard has about [120 trees per acre](http://fruitsandnuts.ucdavis.edu/almondpages/AlmondOrchardManagement/), or 300 trees per hectare.  So a myriad of trees covers tens of acres or hectares.  This is the size of either a small forest, or a working plot within a large forest.

Comment: Thank you! I know I was using the wrong word but for "intensely cut down", I meant people become harsh and more aggressive/hunger in cutting down trees, so I use the adverb "intensely". And for "myriad", I meant a very large number of trees